# Cygwin cannot find termios.h

Tags: cygwin, code-blocks

I use Code blocks 20.03 at windows 10 64 bit, using cygwin32 bit and i am trying to include `#include <termios.h>` bit it gives me `fatal error: sys/termios.h: No such file or directory`

I thought cygwin would have termios and i could include it by default, according to [this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20772965/where-to-obtain-termios-h) .

Comment: `$ updatedb && locate termios.h`, if nothing shows up, google cygwin termios and locate the package to install, run setup and install it?

Comment: I am looking for it two days now.

I ended up finding the terminos.h, but other error show up, eventually leading me to errors when some variables are defined. And to solve those, I either need to compile on linux, or to use a compiler that can compile them. I read that cygwing could do it, but I didnt make it..

Comment: please do not ask in multiple place: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66585206/cygwin-cannot-find-termios-h